# If I pass in a new object into a method each time is that bad practice since I'm allocating so many new objects tha t might not be used?

Tags: java, android

I have a class called `BaseCall` where `BaseQuery` and `BaseMutation` extend `BaseCall`. And there numerous other classes that extend `BaseQuery` and `BaseMutation`.

I store everything in a Map.

```
static <A extend BaseCall> getQuery(String hash, A obj) {
    BaseCall call = mCalls.get(hash);
    if (call == null) {
        call = obj;
    }
    mCalls.put(hash, obj);
}
```

which means I do `getQuery("fdafodafjdf", new MyCall());` means I use the new word every time I call `getQuery`. Is this bad practice since I'm allocating a new object each time I call?

As a matter of fact, `mCalls` is a `WeakHashMap`, there are very frequent `puts` and `gets`, and `MyCall` is an expensive operation to initialize due to so many fields.

Basically I'm implementing `getOrDefault(key, defaultValue)` since it's not allowed in the current Android version I'm using.

Comment: I guess we need more context here. From the info you provide, I cannot say if it's good or bad.

Comment: When this is your full `getQuery`, the lines `if (call == null) {call = obj;}` won't do anything since `call` is never used.

Answer (score 3):

You propably want  to create your own[`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) instead [`getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-). Since when you use `getQuery("fdafodafjdf", new MyCall())` you always create a new Object.

With:

```
public <A extends BaseCall> A computeIfAbsent(String key, Function<String,A> mappingFunction) {
    BaseCall value =map.get(key);
    if(value == null) {
        value = mappingFunction.apply(key);
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    return (A)value;
}
```

You can use it like:

```
getQuery("fdafodafjdf", key -> new MyCall());
```

And the new object is only created when the map doesn't contains a object with the desired key.

---

This also works without Java 8, but you have to create your own interface / classes:

```
public interface Function<T, R> {
    R apply(T t);
}
```

And use an anonymous class:

```
getQuery("fdafodafjdf", new Function<String,BaseCall>(){
    @Override
    public BaseCall apply(String key) {
        return new MyCall();
    }
});
```

Comment: While this solution is interesting, note that OP has a restriction of the Java version he/she uses. OP cannot use Java 8's benefits.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza see the edit, you could "downgrade" the Java 8 features by just creating a interface and use anonymous classes instead of lambda.

Comment: I know that, I was just making sure you update the answer and provide that info :)

Answer (score -1):

If you have to change every time the objcet it's correct but if you create a new Objcet each time it's not a best practice. You could implement another code:

```
static <A extend BaseCall> getQuery(String hash, A obj) {
    BaseCall call = mCalls.get(hash);
    if (call == null || ! call.getClass() istanceof call.getClass() ) {
        call = obj;
        mCalls.put(hash, obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: But the question isn't satisfactory